# Terraform read all group azuread_groups

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-active-directory

I am new to Azure AD and need help, Currently we are using graph api to read all the data in json

```
current_ad_group_list = jsondecode(data.http.myreaqest.response_body)
```

but I want to replace this call with

```
data "azuread_groups" "current_ad_group" {

 return_all   = true
}
```

I need data in list format, something like this

```
current_ad_group_list =  data.azuread_groups.current_ad_group[0]
```

Please assist. Following is terraform documentation https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/data-sources/groups

Comment: Your TF code is not even valid to begin with, so probably that's why it does not work. You have strange `"` in the first line.

Comment: Sorry just removed ". This code I want to replace with azuread_groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code to output the list of azure ad groups.

```
data "azuread_groups" "current_ad_group" {
  return_all = true
}

output "groups" {
  value = tolist(data.azuread_groups.current_ad_group.display_names)
}
```

or

```
output "groupnames" {
  value = "${data.azuread_groups.current_ad_group.*.display_names}"
}
```

or

```
output "groupnames" {
  value = ["${data.azuread_groups.current_ad_group.display_names}"]
}
```

**Output:**
groupnames = tolist([
"All Employees",
"imrgrp",
"N....
)]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation, can we filter it based on application, application_id  etc?